# Read excel content from mails in outlook using powershell

Tags: powershell, outlook, powershell-2.0

I am new to powershell. I do get mails to my outlook bearing a subject and with an excel table in it. I was able to write a code to separate the emails based on the subject but I am not able to understand how to get the excel content in that email and save it to some local file.

Thanks,
Sidharth

Comment: If you already have code that partially works, post it so that people can help you understand it & fix what's wrong/missing.

Comment: Got code from this link.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn189202.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can output the email body from and a Mail Object in 3 different formats:

- Simple Text: `MailItemObject.Body`
- HTML: `MailItemObject.HTMLBody`
- RTF: `MailItemObject.RTFBody`

The Simple Text method will take each row left to right and add it to a string which you could later parse through:

Example email body:

```
Column1 Column2
1       A
2       B
3       C
```

Simple Text output String:

```
Column1 
Column2
1       
A
2       
B
3      
C
```

So you could output that string to a text file (`MailItemObject.Body > 'C:\emailBodyText.txt'`), and regarding you know the amount of columns in your table could write a script to parse through that text file line by line recreating the table in excel.

[MailItem Object (Outlook)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861332.aspx)

---

If the excel is an attachment to your email then you can use this method to save the attachments to a given folder.

```
#Outlook setup
$olFolderInbox = 6
$objOutlook = New-Object -com "Outlook.Application"
$objNamespace = $objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
$objFolder = $objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder($olFolderInbox)
$colItems = $objFolder.Items
#Fliter Unread mail
$colFilteredItems = $colItems.Restrict("[UnRead] = True")

#Change this to the folder you want to save to
$saveFilePath = "C:\myfolder"

foreach($unreadEmail in $colFilteredItems){
    $NumberOfFiles = $unreadEmail.Attachments.Count
    $counter = 0
    While($NumberOfFiles -ne $counter){
        $counter++
        $fileName = $unreadEmail.Attachments.Item($counter).FileName
        $unreadEmail.Attachments.Item($counter).SaveAsFile("$saveFilePath\$fileName")
    }
}
```

**Note:** That this is filtering for unread emails so you will want to put your filter in replace of mine.

Also you mite have to sort out the indenting for the 'while loop' before using it as I can seem to get it to display correctly

http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2007/10/05/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-save-the-attachments-for-all-my-new-office-outlook-messages.aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot Richard. But the excel content comes in the body itself. So is there any way to parse the email body and work on it. Here's the code I used to sort out emails based on subject by creating rules http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn189202.aspx

Comment: @user2310029 take a look at the edited answer and see if that helps you in any way.

Comment: Thats a good idea. But that is not working for body. Still working for Subject MailItemObject.Subject > 'C:\emailBodyText.txt')

Comment: @user2310029 Thats odd you should be able to get the body using the same method that you got your subject. What happens when you take your mail object and pipe it into the `Format-List` function e.g. (`MailItemObject | Format-List`). From this you should be able to see a long list of variable that the mail object is holding.

Comment: it just shows me Subject, Received Time, Importance, SenderName

Comment: @user2310029 That would be the problem, somewhere along the way you have filtered out the other properties that would have been contained in the mail object such as the body

Comment: I am now able to retrieve the Body by using a function. To separate the messages based on the subject am using the following statment ($item.Subject -contains 'XYZ'). This is checking if subject==XYZ. But how to check if the pattern falls in any part of the subject. Current Scenario -> if subject = XYZ its working but not for abcXYZsdf. So I want to check for \*XYZ\*. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I got it done by using -like. Wanted to know if its possible to retrieve the excel content from the mail body.

Comment: @user2310029 Another work around you could try is just saving it straight to the excel format from the HTML body (`MailItemObject.HTMLBody >  "C:\excelBody.xls"`). This will allow you to open it in excel, then you can look into manipulating the date use PowerShell’s excel commands.

Comment: Thanks. But its being very difficult to parse the text.

Comment: @user2310029 This link mite help: [Copy Data from One Excel Spreadsheet to Another with PowerShell](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/09/08/copy-data-from-one-excel-spreadsheet-to-another-with-powershell.aspx)

Comment: @user2310029 No problem, don't forget to accept or vote up the answer if it was useful. Cheers

Comment: I am not eligible to vote up. I accepted it though... Thanks!!